# Issue setting foreground of DataGridRow in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, datagrid, styling

I do have I simple Silverlight Task:

Display a List of Supplier objects in a DataGrid. 
If a supplier is "deactivated" (which is indicated by the Supplier's property *IsDeactivated*) show a hand icon and set the foreground Color to Gray. Otherwise set the foreground color to some blue.
The row should look something like this:

[image]

The colums specified are template Columns as shown here:

```
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="True">
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Padding="3" Text="{Binding City}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

To set the Foreground color after assigning the datasource I implemented the *LoadingRow* and *UndloadingRow* events:

```
        private void LoadingDataGridRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        var supplier = (Supplier)e.Row.DataContext;
        e.Row.Foreground = supplier.IsDeactivated ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray) : new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 65, 85, 155));
    }

    private void UnLoadingDataGridRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        var supplier = (Supplier)e.Row.DataContext;
        e.Row.ClearValue(ForegroundProperty);
    }
```

However, when I now change the *IsDeactivated* to true, the hand icon is invisible - as required - however, the foreground color is still on gray:
[image]

I already tried to fix this issue by doing a *Converter* or *PropertyChangeTrigger* approach, however, this overwrites custom VisualState Styles set for *MouseOver* or *Selected*.

I heard this may have something to do with *DataGrid Virtualizing*?

Does anybody have an idea on how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont need virtualization
try this
https://leeontech.wordpress.com/2011/04/12/datagrid-random-behavior-when-scrolling/